# How to handle large database table primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have several tables within a database with an auto increment ID field set as an Integer value. Records will be added to these tables every second. What will happen when I run out of Integer values? Will this cause a problem? Any suggestions on how to handle the auto increment values for tables that will grow this fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of rows. From [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933198%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> Integer (whole number) data from -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) through 2^31 -
>   1 (2,147,483,647). Storage size is 4 bytes. The SQL-92 synonym for int
>   is integer.

Have you considered [using GUIDs as primary keys](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html) instead ?

Comment: Yes I considered GUIDs but I'm concerned about the performance impact that will have. I also read that GUIDs are not always unique, altough the possibility is very small that you might generate a GUID that is already in use, the possiblilty is still there as far as I can understand.

Comment: I think the doc linked above refers to a number of docs that will address your concerns. Probably worth some in depth reading

Comment: Thank you Brian, I will have a look at this document tonight

Comment: GUIDs as primary key (= clustering key) in SQL Server are a horribly bad idea due to randomness of the GUIDs and the resulting heavy index fragmentation. I'd much rather use `BIGINT IDENTITY` if `INT IDENTITY` really isn't enough ....

Answer (score 2):

With a type `INT`, starting at 1, you get **over 2 billion** possible rows - that should be more than sufficient for the vast majority of cases. With `BIGINT`, you get roughly **922 quadrillion** (922 with 15 zeros - 922'000 billions) - enough for you??

If you use an `INT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert a row every second, you need **66.5 years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ....

If you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert one thousand rows every second, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ....

Read more about it (with all the options there are) in the [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the response, just as a precaution I will use BIGINT